# Extract e-mail addresses from large text file

Tags: macos, bash, automator, script

Is there any way I could search through a load of text documents and extract the email addresses from it into one new document?

I have this so far in Automator:

```
#!/bin/bash

Report=/Users/me/Desktop/mail/cur.txt

for f in /Users/me/Desktop/mail/test/*
do
    if [ -f "$f" ] ; then
        EMAIL=$(/usr/bin/grep -E -o '^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$' "$f" )
        if [ "$EMAIL" != "" ] ; then
            echo "$EMAIL" >> "$Report"
        fi
    fi
done
```

But I am getting lots of empty lines printed to the output.

Comment: There are various ways, but you need to be a bit more specific about formats etc. Please also show what you've tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898463/using-grep-to-find-all-emails ??

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

Report=/Users/me/Desktop/mail/cur.txt

for f in /Users/me/Desktop/mail/test/*; do
  if [ -f "$f" ] ; then
    EMAIL=$(/usr/bin/grep -E -o '([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})' "$f" )

    if [ "$EMAIL" != "" ] ; then
      echo "$EMAIL" >> "$Report"
    fi
  fi
done
```